# Is calling an undeclared function allowed in C99?

Tags: c, c99, c89

K.N.King's ""C Programming - A Modern Approach", 2nd ed., states in sections 9.2 and 9.3 that it is an error in C99, but not in C89, to call an undeclared function.

However, if I try to compile a simple program that does just that using `clang`, then it doesn't appear to make a difference whether I use `--std=c89` or `--std=c99`. Either prints a warning but compiles - unless I use `-Werror`, in which case either fails to compile with an error.

Is there indeed a difference between C89 and C99 in this respect and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See e.g. [this unprototyped function call reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Call_to_a_function_without_a_prototype). Note that it will increase the risk of undefined behavior to now provide function prototypes.

Comment: The undeclared function must match the compiler's assumptions, no matter what version.

Comment: A warning or error message satisfies the compiler’s requirements under the C standard of 1999 and later, and a warning is permitted under C 1989. Compilers are generally allowed to translate programs that violate the rules (an `#error` directive being a notable exception) but they must advise you of certain things. Yes, old C had a default type for undeclared functions and new C does not in the standard, but a compiler can extend the language by providing that old default. But you are better off compiling with `-Werror`. Add `-pedantic` for extra goodness.

Comment: You shouldn't use the hyper-conformant `-std=cXX` modes until you have a lot more experience; they can break the system headers.  If you want to get errors for [almost all of] the standards conformance violations _in your own code_, use `-std=gnu99 -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`.  Note that `-Wpedantic` without `-Wall` does _not_ enable all of the conformance warnings.

Comment: @zwol: Example of a system header broken by `-std=c11`?

Comment: @rici Any header that assumes `sys/types.h` defines the legacy BSD `u_intN_t` types, for instance. Most likely to be a problem with the less commonly used `net*/*.h` headers. I've seen this at one time or another on Linux, all of the common BSDs, and Solaris.

Comment: OK, interesting. It appears that recent versions of glibc don't have this problem; at least, `gcc -c -x c - -o uint.o -Wall -std=c11 <<<$'#include <sys/types.h>\nu_int8_t c;'` compiled without complaint on a system with glibc 2.27 (not *so* recent). I hope you reported the BSD and Solaris issues as bugs. :-)

Comment: @rici Yes, recent versions of glibc don't have this problem, because I personally fixed it. :)  Version 2.25 is the oldest with all the fixes.  See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20366 and links within.  I would not call 2017 "not so recent" in the context of C -- consider for example that PyPI's recommended build configuration for binary packages for Linux was based on CentOS 5 until just last year.

Comment: @zwol: as a long-time glibc user, I very much appreciate the fix. (Recency is relative, of course; the italics were intended to convey that idea. But it's a subtle signal :-) I'm acutely aware that there are many who think that 1999 is still so recent that a standard with that date is suspiciously newfangled. Including a few who are themselves more recent.)

Comment: You /should/ use -std explicitly for all your code.  If your choice of C standard does not fit with requirements for particular headers, then you want to know that!  Without explicitly stating your C version, you are at the mercy of whatever the default happens to be on the particular compiler you are using at the time, and that changes with new compiler versions.